# Livecycle Designer - Link text field to line of text file

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I'm very new to LiveCycle designer so this might be obvious. I'm fixing up a legacy PDF form that I don't have a lot of scope to replace with something better.

All I want to do is to read in a couple lines of a text file during the PDF's initialise event and use those to fill a couple of fields, but Adobe won't let me instance the file system object.

I've tried binding the field to an XML file, but this kills the rest of scripts on the form.

Is there a better way? Or any way?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I really want to know this too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could help you but found [Additional usage rights](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_Ubiquity.83.2.html#1515852) in [Developing Acrobat Applications Using JavaScript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_Overview.71.1.html#1515852).

> JavaScript allows SOAP access in
>   forms. For Adobe Reader 6.0, SOAP
>   access is allowed in Acrobat forms.
>   For Adobe Reader 6.02, OleDb database
>   access is allowed in Windows for
>   static XML forms. For Adobe Reader
>   7.0.5, SOAP access is allowed for static and dynamic XML forms.

See [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference (PDF)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) p. 36.

> The ADBC plug-in allows JavaScript in
>   PDF documents to access databases
>   through a consistent object model.
>   ADBC is a Windows-only feature and
>   requires ODBC to be installed on the
>   client machine.